# Color points in scatter plot based on third variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I am currently working on a piece of code, where I am plotting two variables against each other. However, my data consists of one more variable which I would like to use to colour the dots in the scatterplot and display the legend for this third variable.
Here is an (simplified) example data frame:

```
df  <- data.frame(id = 1:N, x1 = rnorm(N), x2 = rnorm(N), x3 = rnorm(N))
```

I simply tried this (simplified) code to attach the color to the related points:

```
plot(df$x1,df$x2, col=df$x3)
```

However, this does not seem to work. I would be thankful for helpful suggestions. I would like to have it something like this plot (taken from R-bloggers):

[image: This is what I imagined it to look like]

cheers

Comment: is `x3` continuous or discrete? if it's continuous, you'll need to come up with a way to discretize... if it's discrete, you could just use `col = factor(df$x3)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a positive value for 'col'.

**Quick fix:** use x3 = `abs(rnorm(N))`

**For more control:** use actual colors instead of numbers. Strings such as 'red', 'blue' [would work](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf). Or you could use palettes such as `colors <- rainbow(10)` which would give you spread set of colors, that you can assign depending on what you want

example:

```
df  <- data.frame(id = 1:N, x1 = rnorm(N), x2 = rnorm(N), x3 = sample(rainbow(5),N,replace=T) )
plot(x=df$x1, y=df$x2, col=df$x3, pch=19)
```

edit:

you can also use

```
rgb(red, green, blue, alpha, maxColorValue = 1)
```

after rescaling to have control over what color they will be mapped to depending on their value

Comment: Thanks for the fix. However, x3 is a index ranging between -1 and 1... So should I then rescale the variable e.g. 0-1 or 0-100?

Comment: just add 1? it only depends on how you want to color it

Comment: for example you can use rgb if you scale it between 0 to 1, then you can select which color they will approach to as they approach to 1

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
N=5
df  <- data.frame(id = 1:N, x1 = rnorm(N), x2 = rnorm(N), x3 = rnorm(N))%>%
  mutate(col=Hmisc::cut2(x3,g=3))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x1,y=x2,col=col))+geom_point()
```